# Integrating recaptcha in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Have anyone intregrated recaptcha with Office 365?

I need to integrate recaptcha with SharePoint online and I am worried about adding the recaptcha.dll to the references.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done inside 365 as the DLL is not SharePoint SandBox friendly.

However you might try looking in the app store for a recaptcha app if one exists, or you could look at making your own app so that the recaptcha code works off server.